# jquery, click to enlarge image, then click agian make it go back to previous width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, click

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.thekitchenwhisperer.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/BelgianWaffles8.jpg" width="100" class="image" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function() {
      $(this).css('width', '100%'); // original width is 500px 
    });
  });
</script>
```

How do add some codes so that i click it again, it goes back to the previous width(100px)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.image').click(function(){
             $(this).css('width', function(_ , cur){
                  return cur === '100px' ? '100%' : '100px'
            });  
        });
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcE8f/)**

Comment: Yes, perfect, thanks, can you please explain me these lines below
function(_ , cur){
                  return cur === '100px' ? '100%' : '100px'

Comment: Css takes a function argument whose second arg is the curent value of that property so use that and switch the values to return the new value

Comment: if u don't mind, can i ask you why we need first arg(_) in function? what does (_) sign stand for? Thank you so much

Comment: @HamDlink it stands for index of the element, we are not using it i just used `_` for variable name :)

Comment: why can't I just use $(this).css('width', function(cur){ return cur === '100px' ? '100%' : '100px'} ?

Comment: @HamDlink because first argument is index.

Comment: why we need index in the function when we aren't using it?

Comment: @HamDlink we aren't using it, but it is jquery who is supplying the arguments for callback, we don't have control. We just use the callback by specifying out function as callback. Try passing the argument alone youself and place a console.log or alert you will see it alerting the index,

Answer (score -2):

First of all I would replace the **width** attribute for your img with **CSS**. Next up you can just remove the assigned inline-css (which is what jQuery adds) by calling

```
$(this).css('width', '');
```